# Supernumerariness

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

[image]

What word goes in the box with the question mark?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The word is

> AXIS.

Because:

> Each of these is an anagram of a number plus a single extra letter:
>  `FORUM` = `FOUR` + `M`
>  `WAVELET` = `TWELVE` + `A`
>  `EXIGENTS` = `SIXTEEN` + `G`
>  `ENVIES` = `SEVEN` + `I`
>  `ETCHER` = `THREE` + `C`

It turns out that

> there's only one way to fill in the remaining numbers from 1 to 16 to create a magic square (that is, a square where all the rows, columns, and diagonals sum to the same number). That solution is:
>
>  `05 13 04 12`
>  `16 08 01 09`
>  `02 10 15 07`
>  `11 03 14 06`
>
>  And the only word that is an anagram of SIX plus an extra letter is **AXIS**.

Comment: You literally just pipped me to this! Got most of the way through my write-up... Well done. A good solve to a good puzzle :) (EDIT: You may want to point out explicitly how you jump from your 2nd to your 3rd spoiler, thanks to the spelled-out word...)

Comment: I wonder what words go into the other boxes...